# C# active directory-what if a domain controller is down?

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have the following code, which retrieves all the active directory groups a specific user belongs to:-

```
string[] output = null;

using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "???.???.uk"))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, username))
{
    if (user != null)
    {
        output = user.GetGroups() //this returns a collection of principal objects                 .Select(x => x.SamAccountName) // select the name.  you may change this to choose the display name or whatever you want
            .ToArray(); // convert to string array
    }
}
```

The only problem I have is when the domain controller is down. I thought the above code would simply look through other controllers until it found one that was up. How can I rewrite the above code, so that it doesn't fall over when a single domain controller is unavailable?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run the code with your ethernet cable disconnected?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use any available domain controller, if there is one, you can use the name of the domain instead of defining the controller.

```
using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "example.uk"))
```

Another thing you can do is get a list of all the domain controllers and filter them to get the first available controller

```
Domain domain = Domain.GetCurrentDomain();
var allControllers = domain.DomainControllers;
```

Once you find a working controller, you can use that to create your context